# Help me identify whether given linear equations are homogeneous

Tags: linear-algebra

To sum up what I'm stuck with

Let $R$ be a $m\times n$ row-reduced echelon matrix and $W$ be the row space of $R$. Suppose that $p_{1},...,p_{r}$  are the non-zero row vectors of $R$ and the first non-zero coordinate of $p_{i}$ is the $k_{i}$th one. If $\beta=(b_{1},...,b_{n})$ is in the row space of $R$,
$$b_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{r}c_{i}R_{ij}\quad\cdots(1)$$
$$b_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{r}b_{k_{i}}R_{ij}\quad\cdots(2)$$

The author of the book I'm working with says that

> What kind of description is (2)? In the first place it describes $W$ as all solutions $\beta=(b_{1},...,b_{n})$ of the system of **homogeneous** linear equations (2).

I don't see how (2) can possibly be a system of **homogeneous** linear equations.

Comment: Could you tell us which book you are using and where in the book this appears?

Comment: @A.P. The book is Linear Algebra by Kenneth Hoffman, Ray Kunze. It's on 59p.

Comment: Those equations don't seem homogeneous to me, even after looking in the book.